# VBA code cannot run in shared workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Just a concern regarding shared workbooks. I have a script that moves a certain row to the appropriate sheet based on cell values.

When I copy the row, the format is usually pasted in unshared workbooks.

However, in shared workbooks, formats are completely ignored.

I can't seem the find the reason why....

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
Sub RunScriptButton_Click()
'On Error GoTo CleanFail

If MsgBox("Run Script?", vbYesNo, "Run Script") = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Disables screen flashing when the information is updated
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim project As String, ws As Worksheet, ignoredSheets As Object, scheduleSheets As Object
Dim legendSht As Worksheet, masterSht As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer, lastcoln As Integer, lastrow2 As Integer, lastrow3 As Integer, lastRowLegend As Integer
Dim rowht As Double, rowht2 As Double
Dim count As Integer, SAcount As Integer
Dim ID As String, name As Range, allppl As Range, allppl2 As Range
Dim month_col As Range, month_col_no As Integer, next_month_col As Range, next_month As Integer
Dim mcount1 As Integer, mcount2 As Integer, first As Integer, secnd As Integer
Dim monthrow As Integer, script_info_row As Integer, proj_coln As Integer, name_coln As Integer, assist_coln As Integer

Set legendSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Legend")
Set masterSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Schedule")

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Set the worksheet names to be ignored by the script (non-schedule sheets)
' Add additional exceptions by adding a new item to the dictionary with "Sheet Name", [next number]

Set ignoredSheets = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
ignoredSheets.Add "Legend", 1
ignoredSheets.Add "Master Schedule", 2
ignoredSheets.Add "Surveyor Overview", 3
'----------------------------------------------------------

lastRowLegend = legendSht.UsedRange.Row - 1 + legendSht.UsedRange.Rows.count
script_info_row = legendSht.Range(legendSht.Cells(1, 1), legendSht.Cells(lastRowLegend, 1)).Find(what:="Script Information").Row + 1

With masterSht
    'Find last row with data on the master schedule sheet
    Set tempRange = .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)
    lastrow = tempRange.Row

    'Find last column with data on the master schedule sheet
    If .Cells(2, .Columns.count) <> vbNullString Then
        Set tempRange = .Cells(2, .Columns.count)
        lastcoln = tempRange.Column
    Else
        Set tempRange = .Cells(2, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)
        lastcoln = tempRange.Column
    End If

    proj_coln = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastcoln)).Find(what:="Project").Column
    name_coln = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastcoln)).Find(what:="Name").Column
    assist_coln = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastcoln)).Find(what:="Assistant").Column
    'startCol = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastcoln)).Find(what:=CStr(lastUpdateDate + 1)).Column
    'endCol = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastcoln)).Find(what:=CStr(currentDate)).Column
End With

Set scheduleSheets = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Loops through each worksheet except for legend and master schedule worksheet and deletes all information
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ignoredSheets.Exists(ws.name) Then
        ws.Cells.Delete

        'Repositions buttons that get shoved off the page?
        'For Each Control In ws.Shapes
        '    If Control.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
        '        Control.Top = 48
        '        Control.Left = 9.75
        '    End If
        'Next Control

        'MsgBox Mid(ws.name, InStr(ws.name, "(") + 1, InStr(ws.name, ")") - InStr(ws.name, "(") - 1)
        scheduleSheets.Add Mid(ws.name, InStr(ws.name, "(") + 1, InStr(ws.name, ")") - InStr(ws.name, "(") - 1), ws.Index
    End If
Next ws

'copies the headers and dates from master schedule sheet
With masterSht
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, lastcoln)).Copy
    rowht = .Rows(1).RowHeight
    rowht2 = .Rows(2).RowHeight
End With

'pastes the copied headers into every sheet except for ignored sheets
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ignoredSheets.Exists(ws.name) Then
        With ws
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            .Rows(1).RowHeight = rowht
            .Rows(2).RowHeight = rowht2
        End With
    End If
Next ws

'Checks number in Project column of Master Schedule and copies row into sheet with matching number between brackets in sheet name
For i = 3 To lastrow
    project = masterSht.Cells(i, proj_coln)

    'Loop through stored sheet project numbers and compare to current row to find the correct sheet to copy to
    For Each strKey In scheduleSheets.Keys()
        If InStr(project, strKey) <> 0 Then
            masterSht.Range(masterSht.Cells(i, 1), masterSht.Cells(i, lastcoln)).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(scheduleSheets.Item(strKey)).Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(scheduleSheets.Item(strKey)).Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(scheduleSheets.Item(strKey)).Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(scheduleSheets.Item(strKey)).Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteComments

            'If only one project number in this item, then break out of looping through sheet names and go to next row in schedule
            If InStr(project, "/") = 0 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next i

'Deletes empty rows in sheets other than legend and master schedule
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ignoredSheets.Exists(ws.name) Then
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        With ws.UsedRange
            For j = .Rows.count To 3 Step -1
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(j).EntireRow) = 0 Then
                    .Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next j
        End With

        lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'Count the number of survey assistants in each project worksheet
        SAcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, name_coln), ws.Cells(lastrow, name_coln)), "SA:*")

        'Crew count labels
        ws.Range("A" & lastrow + 1) = "Total Crew Count: " & lastrow - 2 - SAcount
        ws.Range("E" & lastrow + 2) = "Double Crew Count"
        ws.Range("E" & lastrow + 3) = "Single Crew Count"

        'Get total crew count by counting number of party chiefs (hide SAs)
        Set allppl = ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, name_coln), ws.Cells(lastrow, name_coln))
        For Each name In allppl
            If Left(name, 3) = "SA:" Then
                name.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next name

        'Tally active crews for each day
        For j = assist_coln To lastcoln

            'Find 3 letter code for current project sheet
            ID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(script_info_row, 1), Sheet1.Cells(lastRowLegend, 3)), _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.name, Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(script_info_row, 1), Sheet1.Cells(lastRowLegend, 1)), 0), 2)

            'Count number of active crews for the current day
            count = COUNTIFv(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, j), ws.Cells(lastrow, j)), "*" & ID & "*")
            ws.Cells(lastrow + 1, j).Value = count
        Next j

        'Unhide all cells
        ws.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

        'Hide all crew except survey assistants to determine number of 2-man crews
        If lastrow - 2 - SAcount > 0 Then
            For Each name In allppl
                If Left(name, 3) <> "SA:" Then
                    name.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next name
        End If
        'Tally active 2-man crews for each day
        For j = assist_coln To lastcoln
            'ID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(script_info_row, 1), Sheet1.Cells(lastRowLegend, 3)), _
            'Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.name, Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(script_info_row, 1), Sheet1.Cells(lastRowLegend, 1)), 0), 2)

            count2 = COUNTIFv(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, j), ws.Cells(lastrow, j)), "*" & ID & "*")

            ws.Cells(lastrow + 2, j).Value = count2                              'Active two-man crews for current date
            ws.Cells(lastrow + 3, j).Value = ws.Cells(lastrow + 1, j) - count2   'One-man crew = Total crew - 2M crew
            Next j

        ws.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

        'Hide all schedule columns prior to current day
        month_col_no = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(2, lastcoln)).Find(what:=Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy")).Column

        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, assist_coln), ws.Cells(1, month_col_no - 1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

        'Tabulate monthly crew counts
        lastrow3 = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
        monthrow = lastrow3 + 1

        For i = Month(Date) To 12
            month_col_no = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(2, lastcoln)).Find(what:=i & "/1/" & Year(Date)).Column
            If i <> 12 Then
                next_month = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(2, lastcoln)).Find(what:=i + 1 & "/1/" & Year(Date)).Column
            Else
                next_month = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(2, lastcoln)).Find(what:="12/31/" & Year(Date)).Column + 1
            End If

            mcount1 = Application.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastrow3 - 1, month_col_no), ws.Cells(lastrow3 - 1, next_month - 1)))
            mcount2 = Application.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastrow3, month_col_no), ws.Cells(lastrow3, next_month - 1)))
            ws.Cells(monthrow, 1) = MonthName(i) & " Double Crew Total: " & mcount1
            ws.Cells(monthrow + 1, 1) = MonthName(i) & " Single Crew Total: " & mcount2

            monthrow = monthrow + 2
        Next i
    End If
Next ws

With masterSht
    .Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    month_col_no = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lastcoln)).Find(what:=Month(Date) & "/" & Day(Date) & "/" & Year(Date)).Column
    .Range(.Cells(1, assist_coln + 1), .Cells(1, month_col_no - 1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End With

'enables screen flash and auto calculation again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'CleanExit:
    'Cleanup code
    MsgBox "Process complete"
'    Exit Sub

'CleanFail:
'    Raise Err.Number
'    Resume CleanExit
'    Resume
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared workbooks have limitations. The biggest one is that they can become corrupt at any time and are impossible to troubleshoot because their behaviour is not consistent.

Avoid shared workbooks.

Comment: Here are the limitaions of shared workbook in office 2016.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534

Comment: Thank you. Is there any workarounds for a shared workbook that you know of?

Comment: If you need simultaneous multi user access, use a database like Access or SQL. You can still have the user front end in Excel.